# Ant Ftp task unable to send file to remote machine

Tags: ant, ftp

Hi  im trying to send a file to a remote machine using ant FTP task . The code looks like this

```
<ftp server="rbhanu"
       userid="rbhanu"
       password="prapanch"
       remotedir="C:\"
       action="send">
     <fileset dir="./ragz"/>
</ftp>
```

where rbhanu is the name of the host. I am trying to send an ear file present inside ragz folder to C drive of rbhanu(remote machine)
its generating the following  error

```
error during FTP transfer: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
```

Note: I included all the libraries related to ftp task its not the problem because i can send files to ftp server but unable to send files to remote machine

I greatly appreciate if any one could figure it out

Comment: "The code looks like this" would imply that you post the code, too.

Comment: Is FTP running on the server? Check and make sure it's running on port 22

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Connection refused:connect` implies that there is no FTP server running on the specified destination.

Can you try the same directly, i.e. without using the ant task and see if that works?

Answer (score 0):

**Change FTP Service Status**

Command to check status list:

```
inetadm
```

or specific (ftp) service;

```
svcs ftp
```

If your status is offline or disabled, you must change your status to enable. To do that:

```
svcadm -v enable network/ftp
svcadm refresh svc:/network/ftp:default
svcadm restart svc:/network/ftp:default
```

Check your status again:

```
svcs ftp
```